# Make my image full width

Tags: html, css, wordpress

How do I edit this in my css

```
.container, .navbar-static-top .container, .navbar-fixed-top .container,     .navbar-fixed-bottom .container {
  width: 1170px;
}
```

The website is  http://insightcxo.com/test-2

I want to make the image full width or 1230px

This is the code I have in the editor

```
.page-id-731 .container {
width: 1230px;
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Img { width:100%; max-width: 100%; } should work for you.

Comment: Don't forget height=auto;

Answer (score 0):

> I want to make the image full width or 1230px

```
img { min-width: 1230px; }
```

You mean something like this?

Answer (score 0):

I have looked at the code from the link you provided. Your website markup has a **.container** block that has a width of 1170px width which is centered by having `margin-left: auto;` and `margin-right: auto;` 
This creates a padding of *60px* because the website with is set to *1230px*.

The image you want to be full-width has a left padding of *30px* because the parent **.container** width is *1170px* and and the image width is *1230px*.

To fix the problem,

change **.container** width to 1230px

**or**

add `margin-left: -30px;` to the image CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the following:

```
.wp-image-844{
width:100%;
max-width:100%;
}
```

It should be specific enough to target your one image and make it full-size :)